# Using Twitter Bootstrap glyphicons in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

Does anyone know how I can use a Twitter Bootstrap glyphicons to replace the image covered in the following example in my javascript (.js) file:

```
var $img = $('<img class="child-opener-image" src="../img/sample.png" title="text here" />');
```

in HTML I would just use the following as an example:

```
<i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
```

though not sure how to include this in the javascript example above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `$('<i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>');` ?

Comment: hi Rich, thanks for your suggestion. How can i also include the "child-opener-image" class in the example above? This is needed by the plugin i am using.

Comment: Hi, just got it working was easier than I thought: $('<img class="child-opener-image icon-pencil" ...) Many thanks Rich :)

Comment: Cool - I've added as an answer instead then so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('<i class="child-opener-image icon-search icon-white"></i>');
```

The image is actually a sprite sheet, so it's kinda fiddly to use it otherwise - you'd need to set the correct background-position etc, so why not just use the class that already has that info!

Comment: +1, just edited your answer with what I actually included. a minor change for my purpose. thanks again :)